# How to configure syslog for logging in Python

Tags: python

I have started to use logging module in python. My python code properly logs via several handlers but in my code I still use also syslog module. When I tried to replace it and add just another handler to logging, I found out that output differs.

```
logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(address = "/dev/log")
...
logging.error("Foo")

syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_ERR, "Foo")
```

The output is:

```
Apr 14 16:42:33 hroch journal: Foo

Apr  2 10:11:51 hroch myscript: Unable to connect/login to fencing device
```

Attempt to use logging.Formatter did not bring any success as only part after colon is changed.

Answer (score 1):

The `address=` parameter to SysLogHandler() should be a (host, port) tuple.  Try leaving it off; the default is `('localhost', SYSLOG_UDP_PORT)`, which might be what you want.